# How to get Cytoscape to place separate node groups closer and avoid overlapping self edges

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have earlier used Springy to generate force directed graphs. It seems to have a very intelligent algorithm for avoiding overlapping nodes or links, and it also uses the available space sparingly:

http://getspringy.com/demo.html

Unfortunately Springy uses jQuery and is not suitable for my current project, and looking for a good replacement. Currently I am experimenting with Cytoscape. I have tried several layouts and Cose-Bilkent seems to be the best so far. However, I also have some problems with that:

- Links to self are drawn on top of others edges which makes them hard to read
- Disconnected node groups are sometimes placed very far away from eachother
- Quite often edges overlap even with low number of nodes and edges (~15).

[image: Orphan]

In a typical case I will have 4-16 nodes & edges. I'm looking for a way to show them in a good looking, compact form with as little overlapping edges as possible.

Settings:

```
    randomize: true,
    nodeRepulsion: 1000,
    idealEdgeLength: 30,
    gravity: 0.1
```

I've also tested the following layouts:

- Klay: lots of overlapping edges and sometimes very long edges
- Cola: also lots of overlapping
- Fcose: makes very wide graphs

Euler doesn't seem to work at all, it just hangs my browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the others, but both cose-bilkent and fcose don't consider self-loop edges during their calculations, drawing of the self-loop edges after the layout is more relevant to the cytoscape.js.

Both algorithms don't make an extra effort to reduce edge crossings, but fcose usually does a better job in providing plane embeddings of planar graphs.

One way to reduce the distance between disconnected components is to increase gravity/decrease gravityRange in both algorithms. Furthermore, fcose is expected to produce more compact layouts than cose-bilkent in default settings.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I have have to play more with fcose! By the way, is there a adjust the way self link is drawn, maybe it could be more elliptical and a bit smaller? And also, do you know euler should work?

Comment: Drawing of a self-loop edge can be adjusted by playing "loop-direction" and "loop-sweep" attributes in its style. Explanation of these attributes can be found [here](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/loop-edges). Euler seems to be working in its demo and there is no issue in its github repository about a problem. By the way, fcose also has packComponents option to pack disconnected components, but it requires cytoscape-layout-utlities extension to be registered to the cytoscape.js instance. You can check fcose demo files in github for better understanding of this feature.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hints - and especially for mentioning the packComponents! I'm no going forward with cose-bilkent & packing. There's still random edge crossings but otherwise the graph is very clean.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `packComponents()` from cytoscape-layout-utilities on a thousand nodes clustered graph but it either runs into infinite loop or just works super-slow (i terminated process after 3 hours). Ended up with my own packing algo which does the job in 1 ms (golang, not js).

Euler is decent and relatively fast, a little buggy though. It hangs when `randomize` option is set to false.

Cise generates excellent layout but the process takes half an hour on my i7 9700.

Answer (score 0):

Set Euler to `randomize` option to true will resolve the browser from loading infinitely.